# Compute `n * 10^p` as accurately as `f64::from_str` does?

Tags: rust

I've got two values: `n: f64` and `p: i32`, and I need to compute `n * 10^p`.

I tried two methods:

1. Using multiplication and `f64::powi`
2. Using `format!()` and `f64::from_str`

The latter is more accurate (see output below) but obviously inefficient. Is there a way to get the same accuracy without going through a string conversion? Here's my code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f1 = |n: f64, e: i32| n * 10f64.powi(e);
    let f2 = |n: f64, e: i32| format!("{}e{}", n, e).parse::<f64>().unwrap();
    for &n in &[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4] {
        for &e in &[-2, 2] {
            println!("{} {}", f1(n, e), f2(n, e));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.011000000000000001 0.011
110.00000000000001 110
0.022000000000000002 0.022
220.00000000000003 220
0.033 0.033
330 330
0.044000000000000004 0.044
440.00000000000006 440
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b21e03b5575a209c35e7152284ce552b)

Comment: Repeatedly multiplying by 10 instead of exponentiating then multiplying can solve the accuracy issue for positive powers, but this doesn't work for negative powers.

Comment: `format!` is not more accurate, it's less! What you are seeing here is the result of rounding in the `format! → from_str` method combined with the inability for floating point number to store exact powers of 10, rather than powers of 2. It just so happens that for those specific numbers, rounding gives better results.

Comment: Reading [the dec2flt module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/dec2flt/mod.rs.html#1-78) in Rust's stdlib was pretty interesting. TL;DR: string is parsed into `(sign, decimal_int, exp_int)` triplet but that's _the easy part_, and the hard part is then running it through a bunch of fancy numerical approximation algorithms until a result comes out the other end. It's way more complicated than I expected.

Comment: @mcarton Well, it depends. For floats that actually fit nicely into decimal numbers (like these ones), `format!()` actually is *more* accurate because this transform is exactly what it's meant for: converting decimal numbers into floating points (e.g. "1.1e2"). However, for arbitrary floating point numbers, using `from_str` then `format!()` loses a ton of accuracy. See the `dec2flt` module that @pretzelhammer linked.

Comment: @pretzelhammer cool link! Seems like a lot of work went into making it accurate and fast. Maybe converting to String and parsing is not a terrible idea.

Comment: Depending on what other computations you need to do, it just might be better to not choose f64 as your base type.  You may come out better if you decide to use a floating point type implemented wit 10 as a base, like the [decimal crate](https://crates.io/crates/decimal/).  That said, `d128::scaleb` is an orrder of magnitude slower than your `f64` `mul` and `powi` call, but still an order of magnitude faster than f64 string parsing.  It will, however, not lose precision in the domain you seem to care about, the numbers that can be exactly represented with decimal radix.

Answer (score 0):

As always, there is a crate for it:
[rust_decimal](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/1.0.3/rust_decimal/)
It is not exactly, what you want, but it adds the needed precision to your task without going the way of formatting.
Maybe give it a try, it is unfortunately not possible to use it on the playground.